# What's the best way to add css to vendor module?

Tags: magento2, extensions, css

I download via composer a module and I need to add some CSS to it.
What's the best way to add that css? Adding to my theme, extending the module css and add more css there? I've seen some ways but what's the best one?

If it is extending how to I extend css it? Do I need to override the whole css file or I can add, for example, a custom.css to it in my app/code or app/design?

Thanks :D

Comment: if it is only for css, just put it in design, you will not override the module for this.

Comment: Add in your theme folder